# Multiple zookeeper server for solr cloud

Tags: apache, solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

I was playing with SolrCloud by following the official tutorial Getting Start with SolrCloud here at https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Getting+Started+with+SolrCloud and it works easily and properly to create nodes, shards and replica's because it has **Embedded** the ZooKeeper but when I am trying to setup **External** ZooKeeper using my https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Setting+Up+an+External+ZooKeeper+Ensemble it shows me **FAILED TO START**. I am using zookeeper v3.6 and solr v5.3

**Setting Up a Single ZooKeeper**
The single zookeeper(`zoo.cfg`) configuration with works like a charm.

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeper
clientPort=2181
```

**Setting up a ZooKeeper Ensemble**: But when I try to configure 3 files e.g `zoo.cfg`, `zoo2.cfg`, `zoo3.cfg` with

**zoo.cfg**

```
dataDir=/var/lib/zookeeperdata/1
clientPort=2181
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

**zoo2.cfg**

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=c:/sw/zookeeperdata/2
clientPort=2182
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

**zoo3.cfg**

```
tickTime=2000
dataDir=c:/sw/zookeeperdata/3
clientPort=2183
initLimit=5
syncLimit=2
server.1=localhost:2888:3888
server.2=localhost:2889:3889
server.3=localhost:2890:3890
```

Getting error on starting **first** zookeeper server

**sudo bin/zkServer.sh start zoo.cfg**

> /usr/bin/java ZooKeeper
>
> JMX enabled by default Using config:
>
> /usr/local/bin/zookeeper-3.5.2-alpha/bin/../conf/zoo.cfg
>
> Starting zookeeper ... FAILED TO START

how can I setup multiple zookeeper server with interlink?

Comment: Is there a reason the dataDir for zoo1 is set for a Linux system (/var/lib/zookeeperdata/) and for 2 and 3 are Windows (c:/sw/zookeeperdata)?

Comment: @pihentagyu aka James Doepp, actually there is no specific reason for two different file path format. It was on the documentation example that I was following :)